# Is it ok to add adSense to an App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, adsense

Is there any restriction? Other kind of advertisements?

Comment: I can't wait until we can pipe the adsense dollars right back into paying for GAE itself.

Comment: @PeterRecore is it available now ? or still not ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's absolutely OK. Why wouldn't Google want you to use their advertising service? I'm sure that any other advertising service is fine as long as the content that it generates doesn't violate the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html).

Comment: When I try to add my appspot domain when registering on Adsense, I get the message "URL cannot contain a Google host".

Comment: @pufferfish: Yes, you can't directly use an appspot domain; you'll need to register a domain through Google Apps for Domains. The new, non-Google URL will be able to be activated in AdSense.

Comment: "Customer agrees not to ... use the Services: ... to ... advertisings.." https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup. Is it a prohibition of using advertising on sites based on AppEngine or I'm wrong?