# Can I use AdSense on an application on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

This question is about permissions, and not exactly about programming. I've read some other topics about it, but didn't find any final response. I got that the technical issue can be solved by registering an account with a domain that isn't a Google host, but I want to know if that's not against any term of use.

I have an application on Google App Engine, and I can't register a new account on Google AdSense. The error is as follows: "URL cannot contain a Google host."
Does that mean I can not use AdSense on my application? I tried to contact Google support but they told me to ark in their forums... And in their forums there was a topic saying they moved their support to here in Stack Overflow.

So, I'd like to ask if someone is using AdSense on Google App Engine or if anyone knows if that can cause a problem with Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2):

[Is it ok to add adSense to an App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245006/is-it-ok-to-add-adsense-to-an-app-engine)

From that post, it looks like you need to have your own domain.